# fgets / fwrite loop php

Tags: php, loops, fwrite, fgets

am having a problem with a loop.

i have a text file which looks like this

AN  Xixerella

AN  Vila

AN  Sornas

AN  Soldeu

AN  Sispony

AN  Segudet

AN  El Tarter

AN  Sant Julia de Loria

AN  Sant Joan de Caselles

to the exception that i have more than 2 million lines.

i need to get this into a sql request for an insert

for the last 12 hours i've been trying with no success

i've tried like this

```
<?php
$file = "cities.txt";
$file_w = "cities.sql";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$nf = fopen($file_w, "w+");

for($l = 0; $l<2; $l++){


$line = fgets($f);
$ex = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);

foreach($ex as $k => $v){

    echo $ex[0].' '. $ex[1];
    echo '<br>';

    $fw = fwrite($nf, "('" . $ex[0] . "','"  . $ex[1] . "')\r\n");

}
}






fclose($f);
fclose($nf);
?>
```

or even like this

```
$file = "cities.txt";
$file_w = "cities.sql";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
$nf = fopen($file_w, "w+");

while ($line = fgets($f, 4096000))  {
    // echo $line;


$ex = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
// var_dump($ex);die();
foreach($ex as $k => $v){

    // echo $ex[0].' '. $ex[1];
    // echo '<br>';

    $fw = fwrite($nf, "('" . $ex[0] . "','"  . $ex[1] . "')\r\n");



}
}





fclose($f);
fclose($nf);
```

but both times i had this in my written file

('AN','Xixerella')

('AN','Xixerella')

('AN','Xixerella')

('AN','Vila')

('AN','Vila')

('AN','Vila')

each line is being repeated 3 times and i cant figure out why.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the foreach loop nested in your while loop, you're breaking your lines into too many pieces needlessly, and your logic is flawed.

```
<?php
$infile = "cities.txt";
$outfile = "cities.sql";
$rh = fopen($infile, "r");
$wh = fopen($outfile, "w+");

//this has to change because a blank line or a line that is simply '0' will break the loop
while( ($line = fgets($rh, 4096000)) !== false ) {
    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line, 2); //limit to splitting into TWO parts, state and city.
    $state = $parts[0];
    $city = preg_replace("/'/", '&#39;', $parts[1]); //replace stray apostrophes
    $output = sprintf("('%s','%s')\r\n", $state, $city)
    fwrite($wh, $output)
}

fclose($rh);
fclose($wh);
```